# How do I get back "replaced" files?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I just copied and replaced files in the exact opposite direction I needed to; from the USB flash drive to the computer, rather than from the computer to the flash drive. Is there any way to get back the files that were replaced?

Comment: There may be some small chance that the files were not written to exactly the same physical area of the drive, making something like Recuva a possibility

Answer (score 1):

You can get your files back when you have restore points (shadows) from before the mishap - with a program called Shadow Explorer. Here is a little tutorial I made to show you how that works:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/132087-shadowexplorer-recover-lost-files-folders.html#post1137368

If you want to make a quick check whether you have restore points, run this command in an elevated command prompt:

**vssadmin list shadows**

Comment: He said that he mucked up the files on the computer, not the flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your files are gone.

But not all is lost (literally): Depending on how crowded your storage medium was, and how many other changes have happened to your filesystem, the data might still be there, fully or partially.

The way it works when you overwrite a file is that the filesystem table is updated with the new location of the file, after the data is written. The data can be written elsewhere, and this is where you might luck out.

I did a similar fingerfudge eons ago, and almost lost a month of work in the form of perl code, but I managed to salvage close to all of it. What I did I only know how to do in linux, and only partially:

1. To ensure you're not overwriting the lost data further, make a backup of the entire drive, for example:

   dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/home/aoeu/drivedump bs=16777216
2. Scan through the drivedump for some known contents of the file you need to recover. I did this with a combination of `strings`, `cat`, `grep` and regular expressions. The method here depends a lot on what you're looking for. For me it was simple, as it was cleartext perl code of which I remembered a few snippets.
3. Once you've identified where, you can extract this portion (I used grep with some switches and redirected the output to a new file

Hopefully enough of your file is still intact to justify the work involved in this process. It sure was for me as a few hours allowed me not to lose a month of work, weekends included.

---

**Note:** The more writes have happened to the storage medium since the screwup, the more likely it is that one of those writes have been over the data you want, as the data you want is now considered "available for use". This is why I recommend disconnecting it until you're able to ensure that you can access it in a read-only way. Windows, for example, is very fond of writing to a disk, even though you're not really doing anything in particular.